# process when have data

Tags: command-line, time, batch-file, batch-processing

I making a program to process files in a folder. but the problem is, the program is keep running even there are no file in the folder. How can I specify the program to only run if only there have file in the folder.

The command I use to process is

```
for %%f in (zeos*,upuc*) do (start teqc +qc %%f)
```

How can the program stop if there are no file in the folder? is there any command to specific the program to only process when there have data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quickest/easiest way is

```
attrib folder\*.* | find "File not found"
if %errorlevel%==1 for %%f in (ZEOS*,UPUC*) do (START teqc +qc %%f)
```